# Microsoft Project Server 2013 Site is Not getting Started

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, project-server, chrome, windows-server-2012-r2

I am getting the following error whenever I try to start Microsoft Project Server 2013 Site.

**Web Site Error**

[image]

**Event Log**

[image]

**IIS Status for Project Server 2013 App Pool**

[image]

**Windows Services**

[image]

**ULS LOG for Correlation-ID**

[image]

Now I am NOT getting what is going wrong?

**Updated Errors**

**Browser-Error with Correlation-ID**

[image]

**Central Administration PWA Instance Status Started**

[image]

**Central Administration PWA Status Provisioned**

[image]

**IIS Pool Status**

[image]

**ULS-Log messages Detailed**

[image]

Comment: Hi @naseer is this error appear in project center ?  when this error appear to you ? is it faced by all useres ?

Comment: Yes this error is faced by every client.I am not getting what issue really is?

Comment: Your Error-Message gives you a Correlation-ID. Please check your ULS-Logs for according lines and post them here.

Comment: @MHeld Please check the ULS Log I posted.

Comment: @M.Qassas Please check the ULS Log I posted.

Comment: The error messages are cut in your screenshot from ULS-Viewer. Could you please paste the full error-messages? Thanks

Comment: @MHeld I have edited my post to add full messages please check and suggest me accordingly.

Comment: Bhai @NaseerAhmed Please check my answer , I am pretty sure it's the root cause of your issue  and you need to restart app pool of your project server application service as I mentioned in my answer please tell me the result :)

Comment: @M.Qassas I have new updates ...I tried your steps one by one and have posted results accordingly unfortunately still things did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact , this issue has a more reason and should be traced physically , meanwhile, I have checked your attached screenshot and I found out your `Project Server Application pool` that running with the service account `psServiceAppPool` has been stopped , so try to restart it again .

[image]

Also, make sure that the `Project Server Application Service` has been started in

> Sharepoint Central Administration > System Settings > Manage services on server .

[image]

Also, Make sure that The `PWA instance` has been provisioned properly at

> Central administration > Application management > manage Service application > click on project server application server > check the status of your PWA Instance

[image]

Comment: Please Check my latest Updated Errors

Comment: I have checked your update and in the new ULS log I have found there 's 503 server unavailable at the 14 line at this log https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1zn0.jpg , so I am pretty sure  it's related to  the app pool of project server application services and App pool of Project web Application , so should you try to provide the correct credential of `psServiceAppPool`  and psWebAppsPool by right click on 

> App pool > Advanced setting > Identity  then try to restart the two app pools again , and tell me the result , also I don't have any problem to check it with you remotely

Comment: Yes this time by resetting both passwords it worked

Comment: Glad to hear it's worked , and you are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am not Project expert but I think I have seen your issue recently. Is your environment a multiserver farm?  A colleague of mine was setting up a PoC for multitenancy. And somewhere there is an recommendation to create web App it using server name if you will have multiple tenants. Now the problem here was that Webapp was created using the App server name(CentralAdmin) server, not the frontEnd server name. Then as normally is done host file was updated to wire servers to themselves. But because of that all calls to the ProjectServer app and SecurityToken service that were suppose to hit app server where failing with 500 errors as they were trying  to resolve on the FrontEnd instead of sending request to the requesting from the App server. You can test the resolution by trying to navigate to the  http://dbserver:32843/(copyYourGuidFromULSHere)/PSI/psiserviceapp.svc

Comment: I have sharepoint and database server installed on one server and my Active Directory on another server.